# Matching two arrays with HTML elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to run a function only if the HTML in my two arrays match. Trying to change the arrays toString() changes the HTML in the arrays to "Object HTMLElement" which doesn't work. Using array.outerHTML() comes back with an error same with array.val(). I would rather not do a double for loop but I even tried that and still nothing. This should be pretty simple, what am I missing?

Context: I'm trying to make a Simon Game http://codepen.io/zjmitche/pen/MpWzop?editors=1010

```
//array content in console
var arrayOne = [section#three.square4, section#one.square4, section#three.square4, section#three.square4]
var arrayTwo = [section#three.square4, section#one.square4, section#three.square4, section#two.square4]

function nextCount() {
  if (arrayOne === arrayTwo) {
    //do something
  {
}
```

Attempted for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arrayTwo.length; j++) {
    if (arrayOne[i] != arrayTwo[j]) {
      alert("test")
      arraysMatch = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the contents and order need to match, or just the contents?

Comment: Arrays need to match everything contents and order

Comment: Are you saying the elements in the array are references to HTML elements, and you want to compare the element content? Regardless of what types you're comparing a single loop is all you need if the idea is to compare each element with the corresponding element at the same index in the other array. Regarding `.outerHTML()` giving an error, that would be because it is a property, not a function: drop the parentheses.

Comment: @nnnnnn So if (arrayOne.outerHTML === arayTwo.outerHTML)? I just tried that and it changed everything in the arrays to "Object HTMLElement".

Comment: So the context is I'm trying to make a Simon Game heres the link http://codepen.io/zjmitche/pen/MpWzop?editors=1010 I'll make that clear up top too.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the comment that that "changed everything in the arrays", because just doing a comparison with `===` doesn't *change* any values. I'm still not clear if you're trying to compare content or just want to check if the array elements refer to the same DOM element. Please edit the question to show how you populate the arrays in the first place, so that we can be sure what the elements actually are.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for starters, you only need a single loop since if the lengths are different they clearly don't match. Then, use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to compare complex values easily:

```
arraysMatch = true;

if (arrayOne.length !== arrayTwo.length) {
  arraysMatch = false;
} else {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
    // Use JSON.stringify to get deterministic strings of non-primitives 
    var currVal1 = JSON.stringify(arrayOne[i]);
    var currVal2 = JSON.stringigy(arraytwo[i]);
    if (currVal1 !== currVal2) {
      arraysMatch = false;
      break; // No reason to keep going through the loop any more
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `JSON.stringify()` will help compare HTML elements. (When I run it on HTML elements I get `"{}"`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn can you show how you are generating the arrays?

Comment: Ok I tried this several different ways and I'm getting the same thing "{}".

Comment: Also, are you ok with jQuery, or do you need this done natively?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I'm trying to create a Simon Game in Vanilla JS I added the link to my codepen above.